# Vector passed by reference inside lambda cannot be modified even if mutable keyword is used

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdin, stdvector

I am trying to populate a vector with integer values which are coming in from standard input as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v;

for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),([&](auto &i) mutable {cin>>i; v.push_back(i);}));
```

However, this statement is not working and the vector does not get filled with incoming values. Can you please suggest where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `for_each` does something for every element **in** the container. How many elements are **in** `v`?

Comment: You construct an empty `vector`.  How many times do you think the lambda will be called when iterating between `v.begin()` and `v.end()`?

Comment: How many values do you intent to input? What is the exit condition for the input loop supposed to be?

Comment: Modifying a container while iterating over it is asking for a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::for_each` applies the function object (the lambda) on each element in the passed container. Therefore to the parameter passed to the lambda is the current elements in the vector however, your vector is empty so there's nothing to iterate over so it never runs. You are also trying to assign the value from `std::cin` to the element in the vector `i` and then push a reference to that element again to the back of the vector along with the already existing element.

So first of all, if you want to use `std::for_each` you need to pre-allocate the vectors memory so it has something to iterate over.

`std::vector<int> v(5);  ///< allocates space for 5 ints`

You then can then run `std::for_each` and `std::cin` into the lambda's input parameter which is a iterator to the vector, saving the inputs to the vector.

```cpp
std::vector<int> v(5);

std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& i) { std::cin >> i; });
```

The benefit of this solution is that it will automatically terminate reading values once it has finished iterating through the vector, only reading the desired amount of values.

## Links and Resources

- [std::for_each : cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

Comment: @stoogie no worries. Hopefully it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`for_each` iterates over `v` and operates on each of its elements. Since `v` is default-initialized, its size is empty, which means that `for_each` doesn't do anything.

You might want to use `istream_iterator`

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              [&](auto i) { v.push_back(i); });
// Or
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(v));
```

which will read successive integers from `std::cin` and insert them into `v`.

Comment: Or even `std::vector<int> v { std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>() };.`